# Do padding and margin from an element change when the position is relative?

Tags: css, css-position, margin, padding

> Relative positioning moves an element in relation to where it would have been in normal flow. *HTML&CSS: design and build websites. John Duckett*

When property position from an element is relative, you have top, left, bottom and right properties to move that element in relation to where it would have been in normal flow.

What I want to know is if those properties affect padding & margin properties.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: Good question! I will. Give me a minute :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been testing some code and I notice that top, left, bottom and right properties do not affect to margin & padding properties. If you give value 10px to property left and after that you give value 10px to margin-left property, then you can get a distance of 20px to left side. You can check it with the code I tested on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ajcremon/3Lqxp0xo/

```
body {
    width: 750px;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #665544;
    background-color: yellow;
}
p {
    width: 450px;
}
p.example {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

margin & padding properties are inherent to each element.

The result of giving a value to top, left, right and bottom properties is that a gap is created between the element and the pertinent side.

Answer (score 1):

They don't. Padding and margin values will stay they same.